# Access Tomcat server Outside network

Tags: java, tomcat, router

I have tomcat 8 server and I want my friend who is in another country to look my web application. I saw many answers regarding such question and followed everything (changing connector port address, router forwarding and firewall too). I am using Zyxel router and did forwarding and added my public ip address in Hosts file as well.

Can  you please suggest me what step I am missing or doing anything wrong? Please note: while adding application in router (Port forwarding) I used server I address as my IP Address and Service Name as HTTP and Port 80.

Comment: if your tomcat running on port 80, all you need to do is to open port 80 on your router and redirect all incoming(on port 80) to your server( computer that is running tomcat).. then your friend can access ur tomcat by typing your ip in the borwser

Comment: @nafas , my tomcat is running on port 8080 but i have opened router to port 80 ..So i think i need to open router on 8080 only. And can he access my tomcat by my ipv4 address or by my public ip address??

Comment: yes mate. you need to open port 8080 as tomcat listens to that port and not port 80

Comment: @nafas my port is showing as closed though i did port forwarding .I checked it on many sites.

Comment: in your router port has to be open in and be forwarded to your computer (it normally uses mac address). if u've done that already, try analyzing your ip by [nmap](https://nmap.org/)  `nmap your_ip_address -p 8080`

Comment: there is also problem of firewall, try to temporarly disable it to see it works for u